# How to change/set the SONAME during compilation?

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, libcurl

I'm compiling libcurl and I would like to be able to change the SONAME to "libcurl.so.4.8" during compilation.

What is happening is that the SONAME is set to libcurl.so.4, as I have two different versions of libcurl installed in my system, one is libcurl.so.4.4.0 and the newest is libcurl.so.4.8.0, my application is not using the correct one because it catches the first one that is libcurl.so.4->libcurl.so.4.4.0.

I already tried:

`export CFLAGS="-Wl,-soname=libcurl.so.4.8.0" ./configure`

but nothing happened.

At this point, I used Patchelf to set the SONAME but I would like to do it during the compilation time.

Thanks